# How to make a cell of spreadsheet to expand automatically on exporting file from website to PC?

Tags: php

I want to make spreadsheet able to expand cell when the data needed to be filled into it exceeds cell width.
I am using export in a website using php and on opening it in Excel the cell doesn't adjust in width

Comment: Exporting to which file format, using which mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

If you are exporting it as a CSV you're out of luck, how the spreadsheet software handles those files is completely up to the software itself, no way to influence/enforce it with PHP.

A possible solution is exporting it as an Excel dot-xls file, not a CSV. That's easily achieved with [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net/) which allows you to set the width for each column explicitly.